# How can you set up website.com instead of www.website.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, domain, accessibility

I just got a new .CO domain name and I'm curious how to make it accessible without the www.

I understand that these two are not necessarily the same thing, but how does one go about securing/arranging both?

I've tried googling this but it's hard to successfully google this when your major keywords are 'www' and... *not* www. =)

Comment: This is a question for ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry DarkDust, I didn't know. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you own the domain `example.com`, you also automatically own all subdomains for it. `www.example.com` is a subdomain of `example.com`, so is `foobar.example.com` and `baz.www.example.com`. Usually you buy the domain *without* the `www.`, it'd be unusual to buy only the right to the `www.` subdomain without also owning the parent domain.

What you need to do is set up your *host* (the server that hosts the actual website) correctly to serve websites for `www.example.com` and/or `example.com`. As long as the DNS system is set up correctly to send requests for `example.com` to your host, `www.example.com` should work as well. If your host responds to queries for `www.example.com` and/or `example.com` with the right website, you're all set. This is pretty standard, usually you don't need to do anything to make this work. It may depend on the host/registrar though, ask them for details.

Comment: deceze, hi! do you do this from the htacces? any good tut? or doc?? thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Trufa No, the DNS system needs to be set up to direct requests for `www.example.com` and `example.com` to the right host. Then the host needs to be set up to accept requests for both domains and invoke files in a corresponding directory. Only *then* do .htaccess files come into play, which is much too late to do anything in this process. Contact your registrar or web host for details, as they will vary.

Comment: Yeah, I did and they did it for me but I was curious as to how they actually did it, but nevermind, I ask them :) thanks for the clarification!!

Comment: @Trufa Well, it's not something you can do, unless you have access to the DNS and webserver configuration. If you're not given a UI, all you *can* do is ask your provider. Try to read up on how DNS works and play around with an Apache installation if you're interested in the details.

Comment: @deceze I will definitely ask my provider they will probably give me a good reference! yhank you very much!!